# Sub menu not selected dynamically using jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am not able to add class on selected sub menu. "Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function" this error occurs. Moreover this sub menu also gets disappears on mouse over. I tried many times but still I am not sure what I am missing.

```
Css:


#selectedmenu
{
background-color: green;
}

/* NAVIGATION --------------------------------------------------------*/


#nav{
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 108px;
    left: 30px;
    height: 46px;
    width: 906px;
    background: #a2d800;
    border-radius: 10px;
    -moz-border-radius: 10px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
}

#nav>li{
    display: block;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 5px;
    margin-top: 12px;
}

#nav>li:first-child{
    margin-left: 10px;
}

#nav>li>a{
    display: block;
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #363636;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 7px 10px 6px 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    -moz-border-radius: 10px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;

    text-shadow: 0 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
}

#nav>li>a:hover,
#nav>li.current-menu-item>a{
    color: #fff;
    background: #363636;
    text-shadow: none;
}

/* sub navigation */

#nav>li ul{
    display: block;
    margin-top: -1px;
        background: #a2d800;
    border-radius: 0px 0px 10px 10px;
    -moz-border-radius: 0px 0px 10px 10px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0px 0px 10px 10px;
}

#nav>li>ul ul{
    margin-top: 0px;
    border-radius: 0px 10px 10px 10px;
    -moz-border-radius: 0px 10px 10px 10px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0px 10px 10px 10px;
}

#nav>li ul li a{
    display: block;
    padding: 10px 15px;
    display: block;
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #363636;
    text-decoration: none;
}

#nav>li ul li a:hover{
    background: #363636;
    color: #fff;
}

#nav>li ul li:last-child a:hover{ /* last item its rounded at bottom */
    border-radius: 0px 0px 10px 10px;
    -moz-border-radius: 0px 0px 10px 10px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0px 0px 10px 10px;
}
```

Html and Jquery:

```
    <!DOCTYPE  html>
<html>
<head>

<style type="text/css">
  .highlight {
    background:green;
  }
 </style>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Log(n) - About Us</title>
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="img/tbLogo.png">
    <!-- CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css" media="screen"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/social-icons.css" type="text/css" media="screen"/>
    <!--[if IE 8]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="/css/ie8-hacks.css"/>
    <![endif]-->
    <!-- ENDS CSS -->

    <!-- GOOGLE FONTS -->
    <!--<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Ubuntu' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>-->

    <!-- JS -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.5.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui-1.8.13.custom.min.js"></script>
    <!--<script type="text/javascript" src="js/easing.js"></script>-->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.scrollTo-1.4.2-min.js"></script>
    <!--<script type="text/javascript" src="js/quicksand.js"></script>-->
    <!--<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.cycle.all.js"></script>-->
    <!--<script type="text/javascript" src="js/custom.js"></script>-->
    <!--[if IE]>
    <!--<script src="http://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>-->
    <![endif]-->

    <!--[if IE 6]>
    <!--<script type="text/javascript" src="js/DD_belatedPNG.js"></script>-->
    <script>
        /* EXAMPLE */
        //DD_belatedPNG.fix('*');
    </script>
    <![endif]-->
    <!-- ENDS JS -->


    <!-- Nivo slider -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/nivo-slider.css" type="text/css" media="screen"/>
    <script src="js/nivo-slider/jquery.nivo.slider.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <!-- ENDS Nivo slider -->

    <!-- tabs -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/tabs.css" type="text/css" media="screen"/>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/tabs.js"></script>
    <!-- ENDS tabs -->

    <!-- prettyPhoto -->
    <!--<script type="text/javascript" src="js/prettyPhoto/js/jquery.prettyPhoto.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="js/prettyPhoto/css/prettyPhoto.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />-->
    <!-- ENDS prettyPhoto -->

    <!-- superfish -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="css/superfish.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="css/superfish-left.css"/>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/superfish-1.4.8/js/hoverIntent.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/superfish-1.4.8/js/superfish.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/superfish-1.4.8/js/supersubs.js"></script>
    <!-- ENDS superfish -->

    <!-- poshytip -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="js/poshytip-1.0/src/tip-twitter/tip-twitter.css" type="text/css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="js/poshytip-1.0/src/tip-yellowsimple/tip-yellowsimple.css" type="text/css"/>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/poshytip-1.0/src/jquery.poshytip.min.js"></script>
    <!-- ENDS poshytip -->

    <!-- Tweet -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.tweet.css" media="all" type="text/css"/>
    <script src="js/tweet/jquery.tweet.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <!-- ENDS Tweet -->

    <!-- Fancybox -->
    <!--<link rel="stylesheet" href="js/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4/fancybox/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4/fancybox/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.pack.js"></script>-->
    <!-- ENDS Fancybox -->

    <!-- SKIN -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="skins/plastic/style.css" type="text/css" media="screen"/>
    <!--<script type="text/javascript" src="js/contecntMenu.js"></script>-->
     <?php echo "testing";?>

</head>

            <!-- Navigation -->
            <ul id="nav" class="sf-menu">
                <li ><a class="s" href="#">HOME</a>

                </li>
                <li ><a class="s" href="aboutus.php">ABOUT US</a>

                </li>
                <li ><a class="s" href="#">COURSES</a>

                    <ul>
                        <li ><a class="s" href="coreJava.php"><span> Java </span></a>
                        </li>
                        <li ><a class="s" href="strutsFramework.php"><span> Framework </span></a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a class="s" href="LinuxTraining.php"><span> Linux Training </span></a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a class="s" href="AndroidTraining.php"><span> Android Training </span></a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <!--<li><a href="portfolio.html">PORTFOLIO</a></li>-->
                <li ><a class="s" href="#">CERTIFICATION</a>

                    <ul>
                        <li ><a class="s" href="javaCertification.php"><span> Java Certification </span></a>
                        </li>
                        <li ><a class="s" href="CCNACertification.php"><span> CCNA Certification </span></a>
                        </li>
                        <!--<li><a href="video-gallery.html"><span> Video gallery </span></a></li>-->
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a class="s" href="contact.php">CONTACT</a>

                </li>
</ul>
            <!-- Navigation -->

    </div>
    <!-- ENDS HEADER -->

<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery.noConflict();
                jQuery(document).ready(function() {

                  $('#sf-menu').click(function () {
                  alert("helloo");
                   var $this = $(this);
                   $(this).removeAttr('id',"selectedmenu");
                      $(this).attr('id',"selectedmenu");
            });
            });

</script>


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You have posted too much code. No one is going to read through all that. Please only post relevant code.

Comment: Please edit your question by deleting all code that is not related to this issue.

Comment: i edited and posted only relevant code now.

Comment: can you post a link to the live site? you can locate where the Uncaught error is within your code. Additionally, jQuery 1.5.1 is very old.